# Why does Dart not allow partial Records?

Tags: dart

I have the following little dart 3 example, which has the error at the comment. I would like to understand the rationale behind this. Why is this not allowed? I would have thought that for the function it should not matter that the argument in the call has more properties in the Record than what it requires. It could simply ignore them?!

```dart
typedef Stuff = ({String name, int age});

var instance = (name: 'Foo', age: 42, bubble: true);

sayStuff(Stuff stuff) {
  print("name: ${stuff.name}, age: ${stuff.age}");
}

main() {
  sayStuff(instance);
  // This leads to a compile error at `instance`:
  // The argument type '({int age, bool bubble, String name})'
  // can't be assigned to the parameter type '({int age, String name})'
}
```

Comment: Records have no "optional fields".  The type consists of all of the positional fields in order, and all of the named fields matched by name.  Two differently typed records cannot be assigned back and forth.

Comment: `Record`s with different fields are simply different types, so the type system will not treat them as compatible.  Arguably a `Record` with a strict subset of fields of another `Record` should be considered a subtype, but things like that don't come for free.  There also would need to be some explicit design choices to make: would passing `instance` where `Stuff` is expected implicitly create a new `Stuff` `Record`? If not, then `Record`s would be polymorphic, which would reduce optimization opportunities.

Comment: You're probably right. I have no idea about the optimization issues, but from a developer standpoint, I surely would find it useful to have the ability to use subtypes for Records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for implementation reasons.

It's definitely *possible* to make any record type a subtype of any other record type which has a subset of the same fields.

However, one of the design goals for records was that it should be possible to *unbox* them, inline the values into the stack or object state, without storing an extra object.

That is why records do not promise to have a persistent identity, `(int, int) point = ...; print(identical(point, point));` is allowed to print `false`, even though it's "the same point value" passed twice to `identical`.

That's because the `record` *variable* may not exist, and the implementation could have implemented it as `var (int point$1, int point$2) = ...; print(identical((point$1, point$2), (point$1, point$2)));`.
It doesn't have to, but it's *allowed* to. Whether to do so or not is an optimization problem.

That means that if we make `({int x, int y, int z})` a subtype of `({int x, int y})`, then it's assignable, and someone doing `({int x, int y}) namedPoint = getSomePoint();` would not expect `getSomePoint` to return a 3D-point, `({int x, int y, int z})`.

If it did, and the local `namedPoint` was inlined, it would *throw away the `z` field*.
But if the `namedPoint` was not inlined, it would probably want to keep a reference to the value from `getSomePoint()`, which would retain the `z` field.

Either behavior is fine, but the inconsistency is jarring and error-prone.

So Dart records are defined such that the compiler knows the precise fields of the record from looking at the type. Then it can safely, soundly and *consistently* decide whether to unbox and inline the fields, or keep the original value around, the only difference will be whether `identical` returns true or false, and it's not ever *required* to return `true`, so you shouldn't be using `identical` on records anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer.
This happens because a value of one type is not a subtype of another type.

```dart
typedef Stuff = ({String name, int age});

void main(List<String> args) {
  final instance = (name: 'Foo', age: 42, bubble: true);
  print(instance is Stuff);
}
```

This is a case, in simple terms, for the compiler when it can be said that the value of the expression `is assignable` takes on the value `false`.
This is precisely what prevents this code from compiling.

P.S.

Additional clarification to the author of the question:

**Record types**
There is no type declaration for individual record types. Records are structurally typed based on the types of their fields. A record’s shape (the set of its fields, the fields’ types, and their names, if any) uniquely determines the type of a record.

```dart
typedef AB = ({String a, int b});

typedef BA = ({int b, String a});

void main(List<String> args) {
  final instance = (a: 'a', b: 0);
  final instance2 = (b: 0, a: 'a');
  print(instance is AB);
  print(instance is BA);
  print(instance.runtimeType);
  print(instance2.runtimeType);
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
({String a, int b})
({String a, int b})
```

That is, the type `({String a, int b})` is identical to the type `({int b, String a})`. That is, they are structurally typed.
Both of them are of type `({String a, int b})`.

Comment: But that is exactly my question. I understand that currently instance is not Stuff. But why couldn't it? instance has all the required props of Stuff and then some. It is really just a question of definition. I understand that the Dart team chose to define it they way they did. I was just curious, why.

Comment: Why should it be the way you want? What advantages do you have in using this? Dart uses a  `Nominal type system`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system  And your question sounds like this. `Yes, I know what a "Nominal type system" is and, of course, I know what a "Structural type system" is. But I don't like it and I want to ask: Why aren't these two completely different type systems implemented simultaneously in Dart?`

Comment: :) Yes you're right. The thing is, in the documentation it seems as if Records are structurally typed: "Records are structurally typed based on the types of their fields". https://dart.dev/language/records#record-types  That's why I got my hopes up.

Comment: In addition to this, I also (and there) read the following. A record’s shape (the set of its fields, the fields’ types, and their names, if any) `uniquely` determines `the type` of a record.  It would be interesting to know what  `determining type uniqueness` is. Do you happen to know what uniqueness is? And what is type uniqueness? Maybe it's all about structural identity? Yes. Yes. Yes, each type is unique and is identified not by the position of the type member in the definition, but by definition. But this does not break the type system, it is just a way of identification.